# JavaFX - How to focus on one stage

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

My application has a main app Stage that opens a 2nd window from it. I want to focus on only one stage.

I have 2 issues which I want to be resolved :

1 - How can I put the `focus` on `only the second Stage` (a fileChooser OpenDialog)? i.e. I can't switch to the main app Stage until user has clicked on Open or Cancel.

2 -  How can I oblige the user to `close the 2nd Stage before he can close the main Stage`?

Right now, I can close the main window while the 2nd stage(OpenDialog) is still running.

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you simply pass your first stage as parameter to `showOpenDialog`? Creating a second stage only for your dialog is kinda .... useless ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a combination of [Modality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html) and [Ownership](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner-javafx.stage.Window-) of stages.

`subStage.initOwner(stage)` -> Makes sure that the substage moves along with its owner.

`subStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL)` -> Makes sure that `substage` blocks input events from being delivered **to all windows from its owner** (parent) to its root.

You can also use `Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL` if you want to block input events **to all windows from the same application**, except for those from its child hierarchy.

[Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) follows modal and blocking fashion by default. The default modality for Dialog is `Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL` and you can add `initOwner(...)` to it.

**Note:** *You cannot apply the above stated rules to [FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html)*. However, you can use [`showOpenDialog(Window ownerWindow)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) for it.

```
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
```

**Complete Example**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setTitle("Main Stage");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        stage.show();

        Stage subStage = new Stage();
        subStage.setTitle("Sub Stage");
        subStage.setWidth(250);
        subStage.setHeight(250);
        subStage.initOwner(stage);
        subStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        subStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if it's a fileChooser ?

Comment: You cannot apply the above stated rules to [FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html). But, the [Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) follows modal and blocking fashion by default. The default modality for Dialog is `Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL`

Comment: my filechooser doesn't do it, it allows access to the original window, can i give u the code plz ?

Answer (score 1):

To focus only on one stage and block the others, just apply to the stage that you want it to be the only one that's active at a certain time the following :

`stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);`